DaVinchi not working on Ubuntu 24.04
Error: Missing or outdated system packages detected.
Please install the following missing packages:
libapr1 libaprutil1 libasound2 libglib2.0-0
but i've installed them but still facing the issue

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting. Take the [tour].
